# How to identify input in methods eg. Subclasses of UITableViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have the following issue:

I want to create a method which accepts input from different subclasses of UITableViewController. If I identify the input as (id) the compiler won't accept any methods on the custom table view controllers:

```
-(void)addViewControllerSubview:(id)viewController {
    [viewController customMethod]; //Compiler does not allow this method
}
```

What is the way to identify the input so that I can use different subclasses of UITableViewController and at the same time my custom methods?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you can send a message to any object (id) - property accessors require that the compiler be aware of the type you are dealing with - this is because property accessors are syntactic sugar around calling specific getter and setter methods.

Instead of using `(id)`, use the class name `(CustomViewController *)` to alert the compiler to the class that you're using. 
Another option is to do something like this:

```
-(void)addViewControllerSubview:(id)viewController {
    CustomViewController *vc = (CustomViewController *)viewController;
    [vc customMethod];
}
```

Either way, be sure to import the header for the custom class.

EDIT: If you have multiple custom view controllers, the you can use `if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[CustomViewController class]])`

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. The problem is that i want to input many different subclasses of UITableViewController.

Comment: @Christian: You can use an `if` statement to figure out the class (see my edits above). You can also use `UIViewController` in place of `id` to get access to the `UIViewController` properties and methods (though not the methods specific to your subclass).

Comment: This may get what you need: 
`UITableViewController *vc = (UITableViewController *)viewController;`
 
If all the sbuclasses are of `UITableViewController` then the following code will get you a warning, but will likely compile/execute.

Comment: Yes that would probably be best since otherwise i would end up with a whole lot of replicate code for each different subclass which will be a pain editing later on. Do you know of a way for xcode to stop giving me these warnings

Comment: To get rid of the warnings try: `if ([vc respondsToSelector:@selector(customMethod)]) {[vc performSelector:@selector(customMethod)]}`